# NumPy not properly installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've been trying to work with numpy and libraries that require numpy, but i always get the same error when running my code. There are no errors in the code itself however. The error:

```
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be 
found.
```

I do have numpy installed. I have Windows 10 64 bit running python 3.6.What does this error mean, and how do I fix it? I've uninstalled, reinstalled, and done many other things but to no avail. I used pip install

Comment: How did you obtain numpy? Did you `pip install` it? Did you get a Python suite such as WinPython or Anaconda?

Comment: I did PIP install

Comment: You can completely uninstall Python and then get an installer from the official website. That will install you standard raw Python with stdlib. [Make sure to install `pip`](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Basic-Part-1-Python-3-6-and-pip-installation-under-Windows). Install NumPy with `pip`.

Comment: For Windows, check out http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

Install Anaconda from the link 
[Download Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). That will have all the required libraries pre installed with it.
That is the best option if you wanna work with data analysis tools.

Comment: Thank you, it is downloading. I will let you know if it worked out.

Comment: after installing it, just open a Jupyter Notebook and start coding as you would in Python's IDLE.

Comment: Hmm... What do you mean by jupyter notebook? I am using a normal IDE

Comment: Jupyter Notebook provides an environment simialr to IDLE but you can also save text, run live code, share notebooks, perform various data analysis operations and much more with it. Just open Anaconda, then it will be just like ypur IDE. or you can read its documentation at http://jupyter.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you run on windows you need to install some libraries that are already compiled for you. Otherwise you have to get the right version of visual studio in order to compile the library

Download the wheel for your python version from this site

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

then `pip install C:\...\Downloads\numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl`

Comment: Thanks but when I try this I get: [filename] is not a supported wheel on this device.

Comment: If you are running the 64 bit version of python use **numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl**. You also have to properly point to your download location.

Comment: Then maybe your Python version is 32 bit. In a terminal run python.exe. The first line should say something like `Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version` Only it'll have your version or get the version from sys as shown. If your version isn't 32 bit then Idk why it isn't working for you.